# Docker cannot find JVM

Tags: docker, jvm, dockerfile

The container that I'm trying to build requires the JVM which I have installed at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`. I've added the line

```
RUN ./installer.sh --javahome /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

to to my `Dockerfile`. However I'm still getting the error message:

```
Searching for JVM on the system...
Java Runtime Environment (JRE) was not found at the specified location /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
The command '/bin/sh -c ./installer.sh --javahome /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64' returned a non-zero code: 4
```

---

**Update**

Here's the entire Docker file

```
FROM scratch
MAINTAINER Oracle Linux Product Team <ol-ovm-info_ww@oracle.com>
ADD oraclelinux-7.3-rootfs.tar.xz /

# overwrite this with 'CMD []' in a dependent Dockerfile
CMD ["/bin/bash"]

RUN useradd me
ADD . .

RUN ./installer.sh --javahome /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: Show the Dockerfile

Comment: @user2915097 I've added the Dockerfile.

Comment: I don't believe this question can be answered without having access to see the contents of the oraclelinux-7.3-rootfs.tar.xz file.

Comment: @BMitch The said file is part of the Docker image.
https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/OracleLinux-images/OracleLinux/7.3
In fact my `Dockerfile` is an extension of what's provided here
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oracle/docker-images/OracleLinux-images/OracleLinux/7.3/Dockerfile
(Pardon my terminology. I am but just a beginner.)

Answer (score 1):

The oracle linux image you are trying to use does not include java:

```
$ docker run -it --rm oraclelinux:7.3 /bin/bash
[root@f95110d33bde /]# ls -al /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64: No such file or directory
[root@f95110d33bde /]# ls /usr/lib/
binfmt.d/       dracut/         kernel/         modprobe.d/     python2.7/      sse2/           systemd/        udev/
debug/          games/          locale/         modules-load.d/ rpm/            sysctl.d/       tmpfiles.d/     yum-plugins/
[root@f95110d33bde /]# find . -name java
./etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java
./etc/pki/java
```

If you are installing java, you'll need to include the [reproducible steps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you've taken to do this.

Note, you would typically build your image `FROM oraclelinux:7.3` rather than reproducing the upstream part of this image build.

Comment: I simply tried to build the app by running the command `docker build -t nameofcontainer .` But I'll try your approach by first running the Oracle image and running the `install.sh` inside the environment. I've found the OpenJDK Dockerfile at https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OpenJDK/java-8/Dockerfile . It includes the commands required to install the OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using the [official OpenJDK image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) from the Docker Hub as the basis for your `Dockerfile` instead of building everything from scratch.

If you absolutely need to use Oracle Linux as the user space inside your container, you should either extend the [Oracle OpenJDK image](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OpenJDK/java-8/Dockerfile) or the [Oracle Java 8 JDK](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleJava/java-8/Dockerfile) instead.

It's very rare that you'd want to build an image `FROM scratch`.

Comment: Thanks. There's an additional consideration. The application that I need to install launches a GUI and requires human intervention. Can you advise?

Comment: You need to work out how to install it without requiring a GUI or requiring human intervention. Neither of these are possible.